# JAWS does not read labels for multiple comboboxes

Tags: html, combobox, jaws-screen-reader

I have some code with 3 comboboxes in a row.

```
<div>
 <div>
  <label for="contactType">
   <span aria-hidden="true" class="required">*</span>
   <span class="screenReaderOnlyContent">Required</span>
   Contact Type
  </label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <select id="contactType" name="contactType">
   <option value="PAPR">Paper</option>
   <option value="FTFC">Face to Face</option>
   <option value="PHCL">Phone Call</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
<div>
 <div>
  <label for="deliveryMethod">
   <span aria-hidden="true" class="required">*</span>
   <span class="screenReaderOnlyContent">Required</span>
   Delivery Method
  </label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <select id="deliveryMethod" name="deliveryMethod">
   <option value="ONLN" selected="selected">On-Line</option>
   <option value="SOR">Secure Mailbox</option>
   <option value="FAX">Facsimile</option>
   <option value="PTML">Postal Mail</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
<div>
 <div>
  <label for="altDeliveryMethod">
   <span aria-hidden="true" class="required">*</span>
   <span class="screenReaderOnlyContent">Required</span>
   Alternate Delivery Method
  </label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <select id="altDeliveryMethod" name="altDeliveryMethod">
   <option value="SOR">Secure Mailbox</option>
   <option value="FAX">Facsimile</option>
   <option value="PTML">Postal Mail</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

JAWS only reads the label text for the first combobox and ignores the label text for the other comboboxes when I tab to them. This only happens when there are comboboxes right after another. JAWS doesn't have a problem reading the label if there's another input type separating the comboboxes, and doesn't have a problem if the user lets JAWS read the whole page without tabbing.

Is there a way to get JAWS to read these additional combobox labels when tabbing?

I'm using JAWS Version 2019.1912.203 ILM.

EDIT: This is only happening in Edge.

Comment: I tried your exact code and was able to tab to each combo and the label was read for each.  *"Required Contact Type Combo box, Paper, To change the selection use the Arrow keys.
(tab)
Required Delivery Method Combo box, On-Line, To change the selection use the Arrow keys.
(tab)
Required Alternate Delivery Method Combo box, Secure Mailbox, To change the selection use the Arrow keys."*  This was on Chrome.

Comment: I just tried it in IE and it works. It looks like this is only happening in Edge.

Comment: I just tried Edge and it works fine too.  I'm using Edge Version 95.0.1020.53